# Vuejs - How to display json value from fetch outside of v-for without javascript TypeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuejs3

This code show the image from a Youtube api respon.
(do not care about the keys & values that i show here because i manipulating the Youtube api results with .map).

I want to display some values (channel title and images) outside a Vuejs v-for loop.

```
<p v-cloak class="title">{{ ytitems[0].channelTitle}}</p>

<div class="mainImg">
   <img v-bind:src="ytitems[thisindex].thumbnailHQ">
</div>
```

I get this javascript error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thumbnailHQ');`

I tryed the v-if= or v-text who appears in some forums or here but without success.

```
<p v-cloak class="title">{{ ytitems[0].channelTitle}}</p>
OR
v-text="ytitems[0].providerName"></p>
```

The thumbnailHQ and the channel title will show but this will cause error and some others javascript functions will stop working.

I fetch the json file from the Youtube api inside a Vue mounted.

When i first tested with a static json file on my server there's no error because there is zero delay, how to delay or there any vue way to stop this error that i do not know?

Like i said, the image and title finally appear with these errors but these error break others javascript functions in my code.
I use fetch normally with some then and the v-for loop work like it should.

Inside mounted i fetch the youtube api then i take the result and map it with a custom function i made

```
.then(res => {
  this.ytitems = youtubeParser(res);
```

I display with a v-for and everything is fine.

```
v-for="(item, index) in ytitems" :key="item.id"
```

From a new Vue data with other data that i need.
I use vue.js 3.

```
    data: {
      // otherdata: 'example',
      thisindex: 0,
      ytitems: [],
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use outside a v-for, how do you iterate all the values in your array? But in any case, you can try with a computed property that returns **this.ytitems[this.thisindex]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `v-if` to check if the `ytitems[thisindex]` exists.

```
<img v-if="ytitems[thisindex]" :src="ytitems[thisindex].thumbnailHQ">
```

Comment: I also said i aready tryed it and it do not work

Comment: It should work except if there error in the other place, or `ytitems` or `thisindex` are not defined.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue on StackOverflow code snippet or any live editor like codesandbox.

Comment: Sorry to Mina but it finally worked thank you, i think it's because every time i did it, it was another one who did the same error. And now it worked but the next one did the same error. Then I tryed to add v-if="ytitems[thisindex]" to the main div where all errors appear and it fixed all of theme with only one v-if to this main div, thak you again.